# DocuSign node js

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I try to use DocuSign to sign pdf file via my web app realised with react and node js. My question is about document to sign. Is it possible to send an email to my customer that contains the file to sign readed from google Drive??

it means that I send from my app a drive document to sign. if it is the case would you please give me some useful links. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send the document yourself, it must be first uploaded to the DocuSign Agreement cloud for processing. You can definitely get the document from Google drive in your code, then upload it to DocuSign just like any other document, you can even connect the DocuSign account to an external storage source (Google in this case) to get the document uploaded directly from Google to DocuSign, but the email must be sent from DocuSign and the document must be uploaded to DocuSign (via API or via web app) before any email is sent to the recipient.